# Trying return array as page content

Tags: forms, 7, theming

I'm working on a module in Drupal 7.  I have three different forms set up with hook_form.  I would like to display the three forms on one page along with some html to organize the forms and apply some css to change the look a little bit.  What I have right now is:

```
  function floormap_setup_page() {
    $info[0] = '<div id="floormap_setup">';
    
    $info[0] .= '<div id="select_floormap">';
    $info[0] .= '<ul>';
    $floormap_options = get_floormap_options();
    $floormap_list = '';
    foreach ($floormap_options['name'] as $key => $value){ 
        $span_delete = '<span class="delete"><a href="#"> ' . t('Remove Floor Map') . ' </a></span>';
        $span_default = '<span class="default"><a href="#"> ' . t('Make Default') . ' </a></span>';
        
        $floormap_list .= '<li>' . $value . $span_default . $span_delete . '</li>';
        }
    $info[0] .= $floormap_list;
    $info[0] .= '</ul>';
    $info[0] .= '<div><!--select_floormap-->';
    
    $info[0] .= '<div id="label_cameras">';
    $info[1] = drupal_get_form('setup_cameras_form');
    $info[2] = '</div><!--label_cameras-->';
    
    $info[2] .= '<div id="set_expectations">';
    $info[3] = drupal_get_form('set_expectations_form');
    $info[4] = '</div><!--set_expectations-->';
    
    $info[4] .= '<div id="new_floormap">';
    $info[4] .= '</div><!--new_floormap-->';
    
    $info[4] .= '</div><!--floormap_setup-->';
  return $info;
}
```

Doing this displays the page how I want it, the only problem is that I get a bunch of errors along with it..

The errors look like this:

> Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line
> 5887 of /var/www/app.local.nucloudglobal.com/includes/common.inc).
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line
> 5897 of /var/www/app.local.nucloudglobal.com/includes/common.inc).
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset '#children' in drupal_render() (line
> 5935 of /var/www/app.local.nucloudglobal.com/includes/common.inc).
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset '#printed' in drupal_render() (line
> 5942 of /var/www/app.local.nucloudglobal.com/includes/common.inc).

The entire set of errors repeats for each item in the $info array.

Comment: Read [Render Arrays in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/930760)

Comment: @FelixEve Thank you.  This does supply information about rendering a page using arrays, however it doesn't really help much with rendering a form along with markup. Which is the real issue here.  From googling a little, I see that I may be able to use form as a #type, but can't find a definite list of #types that are acceptable, nor can find where I would put the name of the form to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render arrays look like this:

```
$build = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div id="floormap_setup">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  'select_floormap' => array(
    '#markup' => '<p>Markup for the first bit</p>',
  ),
  // drupal_get_form() returns a render array.
  'setup_cameras_form' => drupal_get_form('setup_cameras_form') + array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="label_cameras">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ),
  'expectation_form' => drupal_get_form('set_expectations_form') + array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="set_expectations">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ),
  'new_floormap' => array(
    '#markup' => '<div id="new_floormap"></div>',
  ),
);
```

See the [render array docs](https://drupal.org/node/930760) and [What are "#" properties?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33227/what-are-properties) for a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly render the form yourself before assigning it to the array

$info[3] = drupal_render( drupal_get_form('set_expectations_form'));

eventually you can just implode the array and return the resulting string, this way you can also avoid to deal with rendering arrays.

Comment: You shouldn't try to avoid render arrays - they're a fundamental part of core and contrib code, and it makes sense to use them as much as possible. It's also good practice for Drupal 8, which uses them even more ([no more `theme()` function](https://drupal.org/node/2195739), for example)