# Drag & drop upload plugin, how to make it multiple

Tags: 7, entities, files

I am trying to use this module to upload multiple files into a schemma that I created (in a separated module),

https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload

```
$form['file'] = array (
'#type' => 'dragndrop_upload',
'#title' => 'Test',
'#description' => 'Test',
// This settings allows to drop multiple files at once.
'#attributes' => array (
        'multiupload' => '1',
'cardinality' => '10')
);
```

Seems to work great but it seems to ignore the 'multiupload' and the 'cardinality' arguments,

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: If the module provides that functionality the property names will have a # in front of them (eg #cardinality)

Comment: Hi, please note that cardinality is inside an array, shall I put it anyways?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - read [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33227/what-are-properties) it should explain what you need to know

Comment: Oh right sorry yes I see what you mean now - perhaps not then, depends what the modules documentation says. It's unusual, I would expect those properties to be as # properties in the render array itself, not as attributes on the HTML

Answer (score 1):

It suggests you need this module; from the [README file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/dragndrop_upload/tree/README.txt) and [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload);

> Multi-upload support will be enabled if Multiupload Filefield Widget
>   module exists.

Comment: Hi, so my syntax should be fine? thanks!